# SQL - Groups certain records with a count if a condition exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that groups some records if one field has a specific value and returns a count of the grouped records in place of one of the fields. I've got this so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.PDP_DESC,
       CASE WHEN A.PLI LIKE '%DF' THEN (
                 SELECT COUNT(A.ASSET_ID)
                 FROM QL_ASSETS A
                 WHERE A.WARNING_TYPE = 'ABC'
                 AND A.CHANGE_TYPE = 'DEF'
                 GROUP BY A.ASSET_ID) || ' feed users' 
            ELSE A.USER_ID 
       END AS USER_ID,
FROM QL_ASSETS A 
WHERE A.WARNING_TYPE = 'ABC'
AND A.CHANGE_TYPE = 'DEF'
```

If the A.PLI ends in 'DF' I want all of those records to be grouped together and show 'XX feed' users in the A.USER_ID field. Right now I'm getting an inconsistent datatypes error but I'm pretty sure there are other issues with the query. Any ideas?

EDIT

All fields are VARCHAR2

Sample data:

```
PDP_DESC     PLI        USER_ID   ASSET_ID    WARNING_TYPE  CHANGE_TYPE

DT1          ABCDE      joe       11111       ABC           DEF
Feed1        XYZ-DF     jack      11112       ABC           DEF
Feed1        XYZ-DF     will      11113       ABC           DEF
Feed2        ABC-DF     john      11114       ABC           DEF
DT1          ABCDE      jill      11115       ABC           DEF
```

The desired result here would be:

```
PDP_DESC     USER_ID

DT1          joe
Feed1        2 feed users
Feed2        1 feed users
DT1          jill
```

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to cast user_id to a varchar and cast the count to a varchar in order to concatenate ' feed users' to it and have the different values in the same result set field. Also, why are you grouping by asset_id if its the only field in the selection?

Comment: Please post your schema, data sample (for your query), and the expected result.

Comment: Additional info added and query corrected to exclude asset_id from the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/741be/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( PDP_DESC,      PLI,        USER_ID,   ASSET_ID,    WARNING_TYPE,  CHANGE_TYPE ) AS
          SELECT 'DT1',          'ABCDE',      'joe',       '11111',       'ABC',           'DEF' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Feed1',        'XYZ-DF',     'jack',      '11112',       'ABC',           'DEF' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Feed1',        'XYZ-DF',     'will',      '11113',       'ABC',           'DEF' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Feed2',        'ABC-DF',     'john',      '11114',       'ABC',           'DEF' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'DT1',          'ABCDE',      'jill',      '11115',       'ABC',           'DEF' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT PDP_DESC,
       COUNT(1) || ' feed users' AS USER_ID
FROM   test
WHERE  SUBSTR( PLI, -2 ) = 'DF' 
AND    WARNING_TYPE = 'ABC'
AND    CHANGE_TYPE = 'DEF'
GROUP BY PDP_DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT PDP_DESC,
       USER_ID
FROM   test
WHERE  SUBSTR( PLI, -2 ) <> 'DF'
AND    WARNING_TYPE = 'ABC'
AND    CHANGE_TYPE = 'DEF'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/741be/7/0)**:

```
| PDP_DESC |      USER_ID |
|----------|--------------|
|    Feed1 | 2 feed users |
|    Feed2 | 1 feed users |
|      DT1 |          joe |
|      DT1 |         jill |
```

Answer (score 1):

Upvoted MTD because I like his solution more, but this is what I came up with:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    PDP_DESC,
    CASE WHEN PLI LIKE '%DF' THEN 'feed users' ELSE USER_ID END AS USER_ID
  FROM QL_ASSETS
  WHERE WARNING_TYPE = 'ABC'
  AND CHANGE_TYPE = 'DEF'
)
SELECT
  PDP_DESC,
  CASE 
    WHEN USER_ID = 'feed users' THEN COUNT(USER_ID) || ' feed users'
    ELSE USER_ID 
  END AS USER_ID
FROM cte
GROUP BY PDP_DESC, USER_ID;
```

Comment: Upvoted for taking the time to provide a working solution, thanks JodyT